# How to extract a word from a text given a position index?

Tags: python, string

Given a text like this:

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
```

How can I extract any word from it given the position index? For example, if `pos` is 6 or 8, the result should be "ipsum". If `pos` is 18, 19, or 20 then the result should be "sit".

Comment: don't use `str` as a variable name ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen: advice like yours without an explanation is pretty useless. A beginner will have no idea why you should never use str as a variable name.

Comment: @BryanOakley edited my answer with that explanation ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `str` as a string name as you often do in c/c++, since you would shadow the builtin type name `str`.

Try this:

```
In [95]: s[1+s.rfind(' ', 0,8): s.find(' ', 8)]
Out[95]: 'ipsum'
```

Make it a function to reuse it:

```
In [100]: def foo(s, n):
     ...:     return s[1+s.rfind(' ', 0,n): s.find(' ', n)]

In [101]: foo(s, 20)
Out[101]: 'sit'
```

Comment: nice way of doing it.